# how to test django 400 bad request error for custom error page?

Tags: django

How to test my custom error page for error 400 bad request in django

views.py

```
class Custom400View(TemplateView):
   template_name = "400.html"
```

urls.py

```
 handler400 = Custom400View.as_view()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a view that just raises a SuspiciousOperation exception like this

```
from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation

def bad_request_view(request):
    raise SuspiciousOperation
```

Then add a url for the view in your urls py

Link to the docs explanation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/views/#testing-custom-error-views

Comment: i asked about 400 not 404

Answer (score 2):

In veiws.py

```
def handler400(request):
    return render(request, '400.html', status=400)
```

In urls.py

```
handler400 = myapp.views.handler400
```

**note to keep debug false**

for more details refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/views/#the-400-bad-request-view)

Comment: when i logout and try to create a 404 error i dont get my custom error page which i created for 404 error instead i get a error message. " A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.

Answer (score 0):

please use SuspiciousOperation to raise bad request 400 error

```
from django.core.exceptions import SuspiciousOperation

def custom(): 

   raise SuspiciousOperation('bad request')
```

Answer (score -2):

go in setting.py

do this
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']